# Frequency of logins in each week

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose, I have a table :

```
classroom_id(int): id of the classroom
user_id (int): id of the user
login_date(date): date of login
login_attempt_id(int): unique id of login
```

I am trying to find the frequency of logins in a week, so if a student logins 3 days in a week (in any order) the output would be 3.

So, the output of frequency would be in the range of 0-7, meaning, the person has logged in 0-7 days out of the 7 days of the week.

At the same time, a student can log in to the system multiple times on the same day. I am looking to get unique instances across the week only.

The data is for a month and the output should contain:

```
user_id(int): id of the user
week: week numbers.
frequency: frequency of login in that week number
```

I have written a query but I am stuck:

```
with cte as(
select distinct classroom_id, 
user_id, 
date_format(login_date,'w') as week,
login_date,
login_attempt_id
from table)

Select classroom_id,
user_id, 
week, 
count(login_date) as frequency from cte 
group by 1,2,3
```

I am not sure how to go about this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you dpn't nee a CTE for that

COUNT supports DISTINCT

```
select classroom_id, 
user_id, 
date_format(login_date,'w') as week,
COUNT(DISTINCT login_date) as frequency 
from table1
GROUP BY classroom_id, 
user_id, 
date_format(login_date,'w')
```